# WebSocket: How to switch websocket connections from primary to standy cluster with DataPower?

Tags: websocket, ibm-datapower

I am using DataPower to redirect the incoming requests to the application clusters.
I have 2 clusters, a primary cluster and a standby cluster. In case of a failure in primary cluster the requests gets redirected to the standby cluster. But I am having trouble with already established websocket connections. The requests received from them still tries to go the primary cluster.

Anyone had a similar problem, can please help me with a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to "move" a WebSocket connection without a re-connect. The connection is persistent and moving host would cause it to have to do a new handshake with the new host.

There are more advanced load-balancers and running a pub/sub broker for your WS (e.g. RabbitMQ/Kafka) that can handle fail-overs/scaling for WS but DataPower can't, unfortunately out-of-the-box...